# Why does my ArrayList<Integer> contain null values?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList<Integer> primes` that holds the primes between 3 and 1993. There are 300 primes in this range. However, during debugging I see that after the list is loaded its size is 366, and indices 300 - 365 contain the value `null`. Why?

```
public class SeminarProblem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 1993; i >= 3; i -= 2) {
            if (isPrime(i)) {
                primes.add(i);
            }
        }

        
    
    public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
        if (n == 2 || n == 3) {
            return true;
        }

        if (n % 2 == 0 || n == 1) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            if (n % 6 != 1 && n % 6 != 5) {
                return false;
            }
            for (int i = 3; i <= (int) Math.sqrt(n); i = i + 2) {
                if (n % i == 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you show us the code first?

Comment: @DonatoAmasa Edited.

Comment: i tried running your code, and i only got 300 entries and no null values

Comment: @DonatoAmasa I don't know why, but if I run the debugger and pause the program after the primes are loaded it shows me that the list is of size 366 with the last 66 values null.

Comment: I think you're seeing the internal array, which does have null values after resizing to a larger size (it resize in chunk to avoid resizing on every add)

Answer (score 0):

its remaining index which didn't utilize by code, as ever time Arraylist full its increase its size `new size = (current size*3/4)+1 ;`

> *you are debugging for an internal array

besides this, you will get only `300` values no null value.

Comment: Huh? Can you elaborate?

Comment: he is seeing an internal array, which generated during resizing of an array.